# I need a regular expression to do conditional matching

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I need to capture the following three things into variables from a monster, represented by a string of text, on a game I am playing in one regular expression:

1. Monster name (always there. May be ONE or MORE words and MAY include parenthesis)
2. Health (optional, ALWAYS enclosed in brackets [] if there)
3. Aggression (optional.  ALWAYS shows as "attacking you!" IF present)

Examples, followed followed by the name/health/aggression match I desire below each:

EXAMPLE 1: [mob] Crystal Joe [wounded] attacking you!

- Name: Crystal Joe
- Health: wounded
- Aggression: attacking you!

EXAMPLE 2: [mob] Crystal Joe.

- Name:  Crystal Joe
- Health: (blank)
- Aggression: (blank)

EXAMPLE 3: [mob] Crystal Joe [scratched].

- Name:  Crystal Joe
- Health: scratched
- Aggression: (blank)

EXAMPLE 4: [mob] Joe attacking you!

- Name: Joe
- Health: (blank)
- Aggression:  attacking you!

EXAMPLE 5: [mob] A giant red dragon attacking you!

- Name:  A giant red dragon
- Health: (blank)
- Aggression:  attacking you!

EXAMPLE 6: [mob] A giant red dragon (sparkling) [dying] attacking you!

- Name: A giant red dragon (sparkling)
- Health: dying
- Aggression:  attacking you!

I am not a regular expression expert and honestly not well-versed in it.  I created the following expression:

```
\[mob\]\s([\w\s]*)(\[\w+\]\s?)?(attacking you)?
```

The above seems to work when all three are present, but when the health (i.e. "[scratched]" is missing the Name matches both the name AND the "attacking you!"  as the Name (i.e. "Joe attacking you!" which is not what I want.  Note that the above expression doesn't attempt to do Example 6 with the parenthesis.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: create multiple regex, and run them all not just 1...that way you don't have to ghetto hack with multiple `|` and then different group names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not escaping the square brackets. Give this a try:

```
\[mob\]\s((?:(?!attacking you)[\w\s()])*)(?:\[(\w+)\]\s?)?(attacking you)?
```

See [demo here](http://regexr.com?37c5r) (place mouse over the lines to see what was matched by each group).

What did I do:

- Escaped the `[` and `]`;
- Used some parenthesis (`()`), but added the `?:` so they would not be a matching group.
- Used a lookahead `(?!attacking you)` to prevent the monster name from "swallowing" that expression.
- Pretty much everything else remained the same.

Comment: This worked beautifully. I appreciate this answer because you explained what it meant, what you changed, and included a demo example.  I tried it in my program and everything works.  Thank you!